# 404 from Option ID URL?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

http://www.example.com/catalog/product/upload/option_id/

In webmaster tools it shows this address is linked to from a few of my configurable product pages. Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That URLs are not exist, This is the part of a real URL which completed through `JavaScript` when you upload a file to add a product to the cart.

it is best to remove that URL from being crawl by `google`, To block it with a line in the `robots.txt`

```
Disallow: /*/catalog/product/upload/option_id
```

Comment: Thank you. How will I fit that in? This is how my robots looks now:


User-agent: *

Allow: /

Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: past this in new line Disallow: /*/catalog/product/upload/option_id